# Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Uint8Array'

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, yarnpkg, es6-modules

I'm trying to  clone and run an opensource project repo and having hard time fixing this issue, npm start fails with "compile failed error' and its states the following reason.

Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Uint8Array'

```
    const [encChallenge] = await waitEvent(socket, 'data') 
    const challenge = decrypt(encChallenge) //This line causes the error
```

Following in the `decrypt` function

```
  /** Decrypt data used shared key */
  function decrypt(data: Uint8Array) {
    if (!sharedKey) return null
    const nonce = data.slice(0, sodium.crypto_box_NONCEBYTES)
    const box = data.slice(sodium.crypto_box_NONCEBYTES, data.length)
    const msg = crypto.decrypt(box, nonce, sharedKey)
    return msg
  }
```

Changing the parameter to `any` solves it but I can't do that, 
How can I convert my parameter to Unit8Array?

Comment: The answer is easy, `encChallenge` is not from type `Uint8Array`, but your method `decrypt` expects one. What type is returned by waitEvent naturally?

Answer (score 0):

As long as `encChallenge` is a typed array represents an array of 8-bit unsigned integers then you should just be able to do:

```
const [encChallenge] = await waitEvent(socket, 'data') 
const challenge = decrypt(new Uint8Array(encChallenge);)
```

really i would make `waitEvent` `encChallenge` be of strongly type `Uint8Array` in `waitEvent` method, then it's abstracted away and always that type if you reuse it again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should be able to do it for some reason am not.